# Dynamically add options to a list through a hidden iframe

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, iframe, xmlhttprequest

I want to dynamically add options to a list through a hidden iframe; I suspect my mistake is in the PHP below:

```
<?php echo 'var oInner  = document.createTextNode("'.$donnees["name"].'");'; ?>
```

because my code works perfectly with:

```
<?php echo 'var oInner  = document.createTextNode("Newoption");'; ?>
```

I don't know why createtextnode doesn't want to take my PHP var... I thought it could be a same origin policy since the database is located on a server outside my website.

I don't know.

You'll find enclosed the complete code:

In my HTML I have:

```
//select or change a country will trigger the javascript part
<select name="countrym" id="countrym" onchange="validcountry();">
    <option value"France">France</option>
</select>

//Empty region list
<select name="regionm" id="regionm">
</select>

//My Iframe
<iframe name="upload_iframe2" id="upload_iframe2" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

In my Javascript I have:

```
//My function triggering the PHP through the Iframe
function validcountry() {
var countrym = document.getElementById('countrym');
    var choixco = countrym.options[countrym.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById('upload_iframe2').src = 'region.php?choix='+choixco;
```

In my PHP region.php file, I have:

```
<?php

// Get my choice
$codepays = $_GET['choix'];

//Retrieve the regions corresponding to the country
$pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
$bdd = new PDO(XXX);
$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT name FROM regions WHERE country = :country');
$req->execute(array('country' => $codepays));
$donnees = $req->fetch();

while($donnees)
   {   
// I checked the format of the data (no problem so far)
echo var_dump ($donnees['name']);
?>

//I add an option through Javascript
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var oOption = document.createElement("option");

//Here is my big issue:
<?php echo 'var oInner  = document.createTextNode("'.$donnees["name"].'");'; ?>

oOption.value = "none";
oOption.appendChild(oInner);
var parDoc = window.parent.document;
var regionm = parDoc.getElementById("regionm");
regionm.appendChild(oOption);
</script> 

<?php
$donnees = $req->fetch();
}
$req->closeCursor();
exit();
?>
```

Comment: could you include the contents of the var_dump of $donnees?

Comment: Sure. For Ireland, I have: string(7) "Carlow " string(6) "Cavan " string(6) "Clare " string(5) "Cork " string(8) "Donegal " string(7) "Dublin " string(7) "Galway " string(6) "Kerry " string(8) "Kildare " string(9) "Kilkenny " string(6) "Laois " string(8) "Leitrim " string(9) "Limerick " string(9) "Longford " string(6) "Louth " string(5) "Mayo " string(6) "Meath " string(9) "Monaghan " string(7) "Offaly " string(10) "Roscommon " string(6) "Sligo " string(10) "Tipperary " string(10) "Waterford " string(10) "Westmeath " string(8) "Wexford " string(8) "Wicklow "

Comment: Have you looked at your JS inspector (in your browser) to see if there are any issues with your PHP-rendered JS statement?

Comment: YEs!!!! C'était le retour à la ligne automatique!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply `oOption.innerHTML = '<?php echo $donnees["name"] ?>';` ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I tried it. i feel like there is a kind of security issue which prevent you from injecting back javascript through iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting that the indexed element cannot be found. But is all cases, this below should work.

```
<?php echo 'var oInner  = document.createTextNode("'. (isset($donnees["name"]) ? $donnees["name"] : '') .'");'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: it was the php inserting \n so the solution is to do the following:

```
$desc= 'var oInner  = document.createTextNode("'.$donnees["name"].'");';
$desc=  str_replace("\n", "",$desc);
$desc=  str_replace("\r", "",$desc);
```

Thanks everybody